# How can I limit CASE WHEN statements to only show ELSE values?

Tags: postgresql

I correctly segmented a complex CASE WHEN query to show columns for each bit of logic. However, I don't know how to make a column ONLY showing results from the ELSE part of the case statement. Is there a way to limit a complex CASE WHEN statement to just the ELSE results?

```
when (bool_or(description = 'bears')
     and bool_or(description = 'giraffes')
     and bool_or(description = 'gorillas')
     and bool_or(description = 'deer')
     and bool_and(description in ('baboons', 'lions','cats', 'dogs')))
     then 'mammal'

else 'insect'
```

I segmented this into this:

```
when (bool_or(description = 'bears')
     and bool_or(description = 'giraffes')
     and bool_or(description = 'gorillas')
     and bool_or(description = 'deer')
     and bool_and(description in ('baboons', 'lions','cats', 'dogs')))
     then 'mammal' END AS mammal
```

But I want to create a column JUST for the else, so that I can show counts of insects.

UPDATE: To clarify, the else comes after a long line of other CASE WHEN statements that are all linked together.

```
case when bool_or(description = 'xxx') 
      and bool_and(description in ('xxx','xxx', 'xxx',  'xxx'))
      then 'xxx'                       
when bool_or(description = 'xxx') 
     and bool_and(description in ('xxx'))
     then 'xxx'                   
when bool_or(description = 'xxx)
     and bool_or(description = 'xxx') 
     and bool_and(description in ('xxx))
     then 'xxx' END AS xxx
```

It goes on like this until the ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT (2019-07-26)

Since you are not sharing your full query with us - I can only recommend you to perform a boolean simplification of your boolean logic, e.g. with https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator or http://www.32x8.com/ or you can search "Karnaugh Mapping" on YouTube to understand how the technique works.

Another idea is to create a table with your CASE values and 1 column per each combination of values that you want to distinguish. For example

```
case_value | combine_1 | combine_2
-----------+-----------+-----------
bears      |   true    |   false
-----------+-----------+-----------
giraffes   |   false   |   false
-----------+-----------+-----------
gorillas   |   true    |   true
-----------+-----------+-----------
deer       |   true    |   false
-----------+-----------+-----------
lions      |   false   |   true
-----------+-----------+-----------
cats       |   false   |   false
-----------+-----------+-----------
```

Then you can use something like

```
SELECT table.* FROM table LEFT JOIN cases ON description = case_value WHERE NOT combine_2
```

---

You can try with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE description NOT IN (
  'bears', 'giraffes', 'gorillas', 'deer', 'baboons', 'lions', 'cats', 'dogs'
)
```

Comment: The issue is the ELSE comes after a long line of CASE WHEN logic statements.

Comment: UPDATE WITH FIX: What you do is...

unknown_outcomes AS (
174     select
175         *,
176         case when COALESCE(...) is null then 'unknown' end as unknown
177     from outcomes)

"Outcomes" and the data contained within is the WITH AS block this new block references. Inside the (...) is where you list all of the other variables you defined above in the logic.